# ¿Como crear un evento anual en Fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

¿Alguien conoce alguna forma de crear un evento que se repita anualmente en **Fullcalendar**?

Estoy intentando crear un calendario con las efemérides de mi país pero no veo la forma de que un evento se repita anualmente

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel buenas tardes, te doy la bienvenida a esta comunidad.

En [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161654/recurring-events-in-fullcalendar) en ingles plantearon este problema. Es posible hacer un evento repetitivo durante años. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/duu0dx2t/5/)

```
events: [{
    title:"My repeating event",
    start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
    end: '14:00', // an end time (2pm in this example)
    dow: [ 1, 4 ] // Repeat monday and thursday
}],
```

o también

```
{ id:1, start:"10:00", end:"12:00", dow:[1,4],
  ranges:[{start:"2015/03/01", end:"2015/04/01"},
         {start:"2015/05/01", end:"2015/06/01"},
         {start:"2016/01/01", end:"2017/01/01"},]
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida amigo, pero este planteamiento no responde a mi incógnita. La pregunta esta orientada mas a como por ejemplo que el evento solo se muestre una vez por año ejemplo un cumpleaños, no se si me explico.